# intuitive way to structure favorites folder

Tags: internet, browser, bookmarks, safari

For many years I didnt use the "favorites" feature of my web browsers because when I switched machines (I use a few between work and home) I could not access MY favorites. This was enough to deter me from using them at all. A while ago I subscribed to MobileMe, which means that is not a problem anymore. But now I have another problem: what is the best way to structure my favorites?

I have a few main categories:

- work related links
- personal links
- rss (regular and non-regular rss feeds)
- look later (links which I intend to look at when I get home or at a later time, and are not permanent.)

Sometimes I cant decide whether I would prefer

> Work \ RSS
>
> Home \ RSS

or

> RSS \ HOME
>
> RSS \ WORK

but I am open to suggestions :) What do you use?

Comment: community wiki please :)

Comment: As per your request :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use any favorites due to these problems ...

- how to organize
- how to find
- how to remember the other day
- and sometimes opinions change

Therefore i suggest using something like del.icio.us where you can tag your favorites on the server and easily reclaim your favorites later on. Especially from different environments.

Currently i have around 2000 favorites and delicios helps me on organizing them.

Comment: Use folders for organizing. Safari can search favorites. History can be used to "remember the other day".

Comment: The ability to assign multiple tags was a driving force behind the creation of delicious. Each of your bookmarks can have "rss" and "work" and "home". Filter on any one of those (or pair) and you narrow down what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is recommended to avoid duplication of effort by not bookmarking RSS links if you are already using Netvibes or iGoogle. Instead, utilize the existing platform for organizing your RSS links, such as categorizing them under "Home" or "Work" subfolders if you have multiple folders in your Favorites Root. If you intend to create more subfolders under "Home" or "Work" in addition to "RSS," the suggested hierarchy is "Home \ RSS" or "Work \ RSS."

Comment: I canceled my netvibes account ... I dont like those sites much >.<

Answer (score 0):

Categories is the artifact of pre-computer era. If you wanted to retrieve some paper-based information quickly, you should have kept it carefully categorized. These days search engines make old approach unnecessary. You would access your information faster by searching carefully named files, bookmarks etc.

My personal approach: xMarks plug-in for Firefox. You have them synchronized between many machines and you search through them by just typing in the address bar.

If you absolutely want to have "categories", use TAGS instead. In your example, apply both "RSS" and "HOME" tags to a certain bookmark and you will find it by typing either tag.